# iPhone development - Viber integration

Tags: ios, xcode, integration, sendmessage, viber

Somebody knows how to send a message through Viber inside my app?

I've been trying send:

- viber://[local] (ex. viber://63648018)
- viber://[domestic] (ex. viber://08963648018)
- viber://[international] (ex. viber://+498963648018)

with no success.

Any idea?

Comment: hello @cesarak did you manage to find any solution ?

Comment: Hi @ConstantinSaulenco... there's no such option available in Viber since version 5.6, according Viber's support. 
You can share a message, using viber, but you can't send it to a specific user: you'll be prompted to select one in you user's list.

The URL scheme is: `viber://forward?text=foo`

Comment: thanks for replay , i have searched too and not found anything

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there's no such option available in Viber since version 5.6, according Viber's support.

You can share a message, using Viber, but you can not send it to a specific user: you'll be prompted to select one in you user's list.

The URL scheme is:
`viber://forward?text=foo`